# Setting up eclipse for openmp c++ programming

Tags: eclipse, c++

Guys I am fed up looking for a proper OpenMP setup. I have installed the eclipse for parallel programming plugin(software), it gives me option to choose only the OpenMP c project but i want to go for a c++ project in OpenMP. So, I created an empty c++ project and tried adding the flags (-fopenmp) to the linker and compiler. Doing this way, program is being compiled but it is ignoring the #pragmas. Can someone help me with this ASAP, am i missing any step? I want to use OpenMP in a C++ project.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this, and make sure to add -fopenmp everywhere that is mentioned in this link.
[Openmp C++ Setup](http://www.ipd.uni-karlsruhe.de/multicore/research/download/HowToGuide-OpenMP.pdf)